# Spring Add extra query parameter to redirected URL in interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The requirement is to send the query parameter coming in the request URL to the next redirect URL. There is an interceptor with method posthadle, where the change needs to be done to modify response object to have query params coming in the request. Please let us know.

```
@Override
public void postHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler, final ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
  // This URL contains query params, which need to be forwarded.
    request.getRequestURI();
}
```

I have tried to capture status 302 But in case of redirection status cat 200 in post handler. I want to detect redirection in interceptor method

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us some work, SO is not just asking for a requirement and expecting the community to solve it for you...

Comment: I have tried to capture status 302 Bu in case of redirection status cat 200 in post handler. I want to detect redirection in interceptor method

Comment: How did you try to capture it?

Comment: using request.getStatus()

Comment: And response.getStatus() ? I recon that will give you a 302, also get the location header from the response rather than the request

Comment: did that do the trick?